Error Message - Cannot find module 'prop-types'
My Javascript code was running fine on Visual Studio Code, suddenly it has started giving the following error, what needs to be done and why this error occurring?
Error: Cannot find module 'prop-types'
Require stack:

Did you install the project's dependencies?

Yes, and with same setup the code ran completely fine just half an hour back. I don't know what changed suddenly that now it is showing this issue.

We cannot help with the question as it is. May you edit the question with an [mre]?
